# Reusable Dart Code/Angular Dart Components

Tags: dart, code-reuse, reusability, angular-dart

Is there a way to make dart code reusable without publishing is as a package to Pub?  I have common code between a few different applications and am wondering how to structure it and use it with only one place the code is modified.

I have the same question for angular dart components.  Is there a way to create a local package and use that in my projects without going through Pub?

Maybe I am completely misunderstanding the package structure, but I thought that is for published packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- Install your own pub server. See the [pub_server](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_server) package.
- Work with [Git packages](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#git-packages)
- Work with [Path packages](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#path-packages)